# PHP and MySQL vote system OOP

Tags: php, mysql, count

To begin with we're beginners to PHP, we're studying Multimedia Design and we have been assigned to make a website in plain HTML. Furthermore we also have to include some PHP (which must be object-oriented). Our idea is to call the URL from our Youtube videos in our database and each video should have a vote button attached.

We can easily call our videos to a specific page in a div box on our website. This is our video_class.php:

```
<?php class Video {
private $db;    
public function insertVideo($videoId) {
    $row = $this->db->query("SELECT url FROM video WHERE id = ".$videoId);
    $ost = $this->db->loadRows($row);

    echo '<iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $ost[0]['url'] . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}

public function setDatabaseConnection($db) {
    $this->db = $db;
} } ?>
```

And the page we're loading it to:

```
<?php // Create database connection

// Load Database class file
require_once 'db_class.php'; 

//Creating new object instance from Database class
$db = new event(); 

// Run initiate function and provide credentials.
$db->initiate("localhost","root","","event"); 


$db->connect();                 // Connect to MySQL database

// Load Video class file
require_once 'video_class.php'; 


$video  = new Video;
$video->setDatabaseConnection($db);

$row=$db->query("SELECT url FROM video WHERE id = 1");
$ost=$db->loadRows($row);
//var_dump($ost);
$row1=$db->query("SELECT url FROM video WHERE id = 2");
$ost1=$db->loadRows($row1);
//var_dump($ost1);
$row2=$db->query("SELECT url FROM video WHERE id = 3");
$ost2=$db->loadRows($row2);
//var_dump($ost2); ?>
```

HTML:

```
    <center><div class="video_clip">

<?php echo '<iframe width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $ost[0]['url'] . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'; ?>

        <a href="events_vote.php?userid=1&videoid=1"><img src="images/vote.png"></a>

        </div><!--video_clip end-->
```

But the real problem is next:

We have 3 videos you can vote on by clicking on the vote button, under each video. Each button must count the clicks and store it in our database. We have absolutely no clue how to make this possible. Our teacher told to link to a subpage (for example, "vote.php"). On that page we should use:

- $_GET[id]
- fetch id from $get
- get current votes from video where id = 1/2/3
- add+1
- save votes in video where id=1
- and finish with a redirect

Can someone help us? We have found a few possible solutions on the forums, but still no luck! Sorry for the long post and too much text :)

DATABASE STRUCTURE:

```
Table name:
users

Table comments: users

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments    MIME

id  int(11) No          
videoId int(11) No          

Table name:
video

Table comments: video

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments    MIME

id  int(11) No          
url varchar(50) No
```

Comment: This have to be the way he told you or you can use other ways, like AJAX? If yes, it will more simple than the way he told.

Comment: Your teacher is right, that should work. What is your problem with his solution, where exactly are you stuck? Please post your code.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown they are just learning HTML & PHP - don't confuse them with Javascript & Ajax ;)

Comment: @Beat - We're stuck because we havn't made the vote.php yet, and to be honest the whole coding-part we're not completly familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it simple, you might want to skip the part where the page doesn't reload. You can make a button do all sorts of javascript tricks (google `jquery` and `ajax`), but there's no need for this.

supposing your url is yourfile.php

- Make a link called upvote beneath each video linking it to yourfile.php?voteid=xx
  where xx is the id of the video
- if you click the link, you get redirected to the same page, but now you have a get parameter
- In your code, before you show the page, check if any votes are being cast

  ```
  if(isset($_GET['voteid']){
      //save vote!
  }
  ```

Now you are on the same page, you retrieve the votes (one is higher then it was before), and you can just keep on going.

Comment: Thanks. We can not use jquery, only PHP and OOP. Our URLs are stored in our database in different tables. We have not created the vote.php file yet since we dont know how to get started. The quotes I stated is what our teacher told us vote.php should include.

Comment: The part where I type "there's no need for this" means there's no need for jquery. I understood that part. I have given you almost an exact method to get stuff from a paramter? I'm not sure what more you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help. We pasted your code into our php and our links looks like this now:
<a href="events_vote.php?userid=1&videoid=1"><img src="images/vote.png"></a>

Where userid=1(only 1 user in our database) and videoid(our table video and the ids 1,2,3 youtube links.) Where is the counts stored?
Sorry for being a php-beginner.

Comment: this is maybe not the best place for a full lesson in how to open a database connection etc. Please check out the faq about the kind of questions are best fit :) .. please google some tutorial about php and mysql first :)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite open-ended, so I'll add some clues to get you going.

Firstly, since your votes will affect the database, you should use `post` and not `get` (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_meaning) for more details)<sup>1</sup>. Once you've dealt with the operation, you can then do your redirect.

So, under your `<iframe>`, set up a `<form>` with a `post` method. In it, add three `input` tags each having a type of `submit`, and each having a different `name` attribute. For your `action`, you can aim it at a different page if you want to, but since it is simple I would point it at itself. Thus, use `<?php echo $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] ?>` for the time being.

OK, so this will send the post data to the same page. Thus, in your page PHP, just after your database initialisation, catch the post op like so:

```
// Your existing code
$db->connect();                 // Connect to MySQL database

// New code
if ($_POST) {
    print_r($_POST);
    exit();
    // @todo Parse the result in your POST array
    // @todo Save the result in the database
    // @todo Redirect to self
}

// Load Video class file
require_once 'video_class.php';
```

What that will do is dump the post data on the screen, and then exit immediately. This is a good prototyping approach to see that you're on the right track.

Adding @todo notes is quite a good approach too - do these in order, and delete the comment when that piece is written and tested. Don't forget to add new comments explaining code, if appropriate.

<sup>1</sup> If using the `$_GET` array is an essential component of the exercise, then you *could* use three post forms, each with their own button, and with the action containing a separate query string that will appear in the `$_GET` array. However I'd argue that's a bit convoluted, and probably not the best way to achieve this in practice.

Comment: Ok so we tryed this now. And we get this result:A blank page with
Array ( [vote1] => submit ) ?

Comment: Great! And if you had other buttons in the same form, then you could call them different things (maybe "upvote" and "downvote" etc). So you now have a way to differentiate between various kinds of vote. Now, you'll want to also pass to your post handler the video ID, which you can either do in the action (as a query string) or as a hidden field. Do that next? After that, remove the `print_r` and `exit()` from your code, and start coding the three `@todo` items I indicated.